# Exchange Webservices (EWS) UpdateItems error 503

Tags: exchangewebservices

if i try to update more than one appointment with the Service.UpdateItems methode the server returns an 503 error.
My Code:

```
service.UpdateItems(appointments,folderID,ConflictResolutionMode.AutoResolve, null, SendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode.SendToNone);
```

Updating a single appointment with the Appointment.Update methode works.

Has anyone an idea why Service.UpdateItems does not work ?

Comment: I find another solution to update more than one item (appointment): 
`
foreach (Appointment appointment in appointments)
                {
                    Appointment appointmentToUpdate = Appointment.Bind(service, appointment.Id);
/*Updatecode*/       appointmentToUpdate.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AutoResolve, SendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode.SendToNone);
                }
`

Comment: Have you seen the sample for batching updates on this page: [How to: Process calendar items in batches in Exchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn626016(v=exchg.150).aspx)?

Comment: Hi Mimi, thank you for your reply. Yes i tree it like the example but the UpdateItems methode does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You may be getting throttled by Exchange by trying to execute too many updates at once. Try smaller batches - of 10 items, or try spacing your requests with longer breaks between them.

As it is described [here](http://calendarservermigration.blogspot.com/2013/07/throttling-in-exchange-2013.html), there are three response codes which may indicate a throtting problem:

- HTTP Status 503   Indicates that EWS requests are queuing with IIS. The client should delay sending additional requests until a later time.
- HTTP Status 500 - Indicates an internal server error with the **ErrorServerBusy** error code. This indicates that the client should delay sending additional requests until a later time. The response may contain a back off hint called BackOffMilliseconds. If present, the value of BackOffMilliseconds should be used as the duration until the client resubmits a request.
- HTTP Status 200 - Contains an EWS schema-based error response with an **ErrorInternalServerError** error code. An inner **ErrorServerBusy** error code may be present. This indicates that the client should delay sending additional requests until a later time.